# How can I tell if the Debian installer has booted in UEFI mode or not?

Tags: uefi, debian-installer

[The Debian Wiki UEFI page](https://wiki.debian.org/UEFI)

says

> Troubleshooting
>
> How to tell if you've booted via UEFI
>   The Debian installer splash screen will say it's the UEFI installer, and will look slightly different to the equivalent screen in BIOS mode. BIOS boot is done via isolinux/syslinux, but UEFI boot is done using grub.
>
> Later on, the thing to look for is the directory /sys/firmware/efi. If that exists, the system is running in UEFI mode.

There is also a related question on Ask Ubuntu:
[How can I tell if my system was booted as EFI/UEFI or BIOS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162564/how-can-i-tell-if-my-system-was-booted-as-efi-uefi-or-bios)

However, the Wiki page is missing some details. Does the splash screen show up in both text mode as well as in graphical mode? Can someone provide a screenshot of what the EFI/UEFI and BIOS screens look like?

And how would one "look for" the directory `/sys/firmware/efi` in the Debian installer? Drop to a shell?

Comment: For the second part, you can open a shell on VTs 2 and 3 (press Alt+F2 or Alt+F3, then Enter). VT 4 shows the installation logs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's on the splash screen before you pick text or graphical install. Note the "Debian GNU/Linux UEFI Installer menu" at the top, right under the centered name/version:

[image: Debian Installer in booting in UEFI mode]

Here, for comparison, is the legacy BIOS splash screen. Note the lack of UEFI message up top, and the different highlighting of the menu options. Also an extra "help" option:

[image]

And to look for that directory, yes, drop to a shell. Easiest by switching to virtual terminal 2 or 3.